# I am creating a selection using arrays that read data from a file

Tags: java, arrays, oop, error-handling, file-io

When running the getGrades() method, it keeps returning B+. I dont know whats wrong, I need help. I will share the code

```
        try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("src//inheritance//course.txt")));
    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
        
        courseCode[i] = input.nextLine();
        courseName[i] = input.nextLine();
        session[i] = input.nextLine();
        semester[i] = input.nextLine();
        mark[i] = input.nextLine();
        

        actualMark[i]=Integer.parseInt(mark[i]);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
        
    }
    
    public String getGrade() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
        if (actualMark[i] >= 85) {
            return "A";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 75) {
            return "A-";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 70) {
            return "B+";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 65) {
            return "B";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 60) {
            return "B-";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 55) {
            return "C+";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 50) {
            return "C";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 45) {
            return "D";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 35) {
            return "E";
        } else if (actualMark[i] < 35) {
            return "F";
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
    
class Tester3{

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    PersonProfile a = new PersonProfile("Theshue", "Male", "11/12/2003");
    Student b = new Student("Raju","Male", "11/12/2003");
    System.out.println(b.toString2());
    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
        System.out.println("The course code is "+ b.courseCode[i]);
        System.out.println("The course name is "+ b.courseName[i]);
        System.out.println("The session is "+ b.session[i]);
        System.out.println("The semester is "+ b.semester[i]);
        System.out.println("The mark is "+ b.actualMark[i]);
        System.out.println("The grade is " + b.getGrade());
    }
    }
  
}
```

output=
The name is Raju
The Gender is Male
The date is 11/12/2003
The course code is WMES1105
The course name is Principle of Information Systems
The session is 2009
The semester is 1
The mark is 74
The grade is B+
The course code is WXES1109
The course name is Systems and Computers Organization
The session is 2009
The semester is 1
The mark is 60
The grade is B+
The course code is WXES1112
The course name is Computing Mathematics 1
The session is 2009
The semester is 2
The mark is 82
The grade is B+
The course code is WXES1114
The course name is Programming I
The session is 2009
The semester is 2
The mark is 52
The grade is B+
The course code is GXEX1411
The course name is Ethnic Relations
The session is 2009
The semester is 2
The mark is 43
The grade is B+

the problem is, the grades for all is b+ when thats not the case. In the output, for the getGrades() part I need it to show the grades for each of the mark instead of showing only B+. I cant seem to solve this. I tried using chatgpt but after countless attempts I feel that this code needs a touch of humanity to save. Need help debugging this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getGrade() currently has a loop (which is wrong) - you want to pass in the grade actualMark[i] and figure out the string based on that.

```
public String getGrade(int grade) {
    if (grade >= 85) {
            return "A";
     else if (grade >= 75) {
            return "A-";
      } 
      ....
```

And change the calling code to pass in `actualMark[i]`

Comment: getGrade(int i)    presuming the array actualMark[i] is global and properly reserved for the number of persons to be read.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that your getGrade method always returns the grade based on the first mark in the actualMark array and doesn't consider other marks. This is because you have a return statement inside the loop, and it exits the loop and returns the grade based on the first mark it encounters.

To fix this issue in another way, you could iterate through all the marks, calculate the grade for each mark, and store the grades in an array. Then, you can return the array of grades or use it as needed.

```
public String[] getGrades() {
    String[] grades = new String[5]; // Assuming you have 5 marks
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (actualMark[i] >= 85) {
            grades[i] = "A";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 75) {
            grades[i] = "A-";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 70) {
            grades[i] = "B+";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 65) {
            grades[i] = "B";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 60) {
            grades[i] = "B-";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 55) {
            grades[i] = "C+";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 50) {
            grades[i] = "C";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 45) {
            grades[i] = "D";
        } else if (actualMark[i] >= 35) {
            grades[i] = "E";
        } else if (actualMark[i] < 35) {
            grades[i] = "F";
        }
    }
    return grades;
}
```

And for your main:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println("The course code is " + b.courseCode[i]);
    System.out.println("The course name is " + b.courseName[i]);
    System.out.println("The session is " + b.session[i]);
    System.out.println("The semester is " + b.semester[i]);
    System.out.println("The mark is " + b.actualMark[i]);
    System.out.println("The grade is " + b.getGrades()[i]);
}
```